# Can not get Address of the current master when I use mongo-java-driver-3.6.0

Tags: java, mongodb

I followed the [document](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/Mongo.html) of mongodb to get the address of the current master. With the sample code here.

`MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(dbURI));
 client.getAddress();`

When I used mongo-java-driver-3.6.0, in Window with Intellij it worked. But in ubuntu, it's not work, I can't get the address with command `java -cp $SOURCE_ROOT/mongo-java-driver/mongo-java-driver/build/libs/mongo-java-driver-3.6.0.jar test.java`. I don't know what happened, I don't know why it's not work, is there have another solution to get the address? Thanks a lot.

Comment: why do you need it?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or just a empty returned value? Thats a valid code.

Comment: thanks for replying. Because I need to validate mongodb failover. In IntelliJ, I use [String Connection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-connection-examples) , it didn't work to connect to replica  set(3 nodes:primary, secondary, arbiter), but i check it in subsystem with ubuntu, it connected well. Then I get Adress, it return `java.lang.NullpointerExeption`

Comment: Although, I test connection  successfully to mongodb to one node(primary or secondary) and can get address of the current master with intellj.

Comment: So, I think getAddress function only works with one node, it cannot get address the current node when i connect to replica set(3 nodes)